# htaccess not redirecting properly with rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a simple htaccess file that does the following:

1. Redirects all http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com
2. Allows the '.php' extension to be dropped from file names
3. Allows http://www.domain.com/page/var and http://www.domain.com/page/var/ to be seen as http://www.domain.com/page?u=var
4. Rewrites all http://www.domain.com/page?u=var to http://www.domain.com/page/var

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    IndexIgnore .htaccess
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php

    RewriteRule page1/(.*)/$ /page1?u=$1
    RewriteRule page1/(.*)$ /page1?u=$1
    RewriteRule page2/(.*)/$ /page2?t=$1
    RewriteRule page2/(.*)$ /page2?t=$1

    ErrorDocument 400 http://www.domain.com/error?e=400
    ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domain.com/error?e=401
    ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com/error?e=403
    ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/error?e=404
    ErrorDocument 500 http://www.domain.com/error?e=500

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    IndexIgnore .htaccess
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

 #Remove .php 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\?u=([^\s]+)
    RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [NE,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /page?u=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your hataccess? I have tested this on my apache server, and it's working  fine.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to match my htaccess file exactly (except for the domain name and file names).